# string split containing Umlaut ä in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to split string containing Umlaut ä (german character) but after split it is encoded umlaut character. Please see below.

```
>>> k = 'A|B|C|AT|Dxbensäce|S|'  
>>> re.split('\|\w+\|',k)
```

['A', 'C', 'Dxbens\xc3\xa4ce', '']

I need to get the output as below:
  ['A', 'C', 'Dxbensäce', '']

Please suggest.

I need to add some more points.
I need to split above string and store into the list, and compare this values with the other list values (same value are added into to this second list).
Since first list value is converted to unicode comparison is failing.
Note: here I am not printing the values. I know by using print I will get correct umlaut values.
First list values are filled with split statement and second list value shall be hard coded values.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is directly in your handling of strings and encoding, and not split:

```
In [1]: k = 'A|B|C|AT|Dxbensäce|S|'  
In [3]: k
Out[3]: 'A|B|C|AT|Dxbens\xc3\xa4ce|S|'
In [9]: print(k)
A|B|C|AT|Dxbensäce|S|
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `unicode` type, to handle text instead of bytestrings (`str` on Python 2). Use `u''` unicode literals or add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top of the module
2. Don't confuse an object and its text representation (`repr()`).
   Printing a Python list calls `repr()` on its items. To display non-printable in ascii characters (on Python 2), format the list yourself e.g.:

   ```
   print ":".join(some_list)
   ```

Unrelated: if you have non-ascii literal characters (e.g., `u'ä'`) in your Python source then you should make sure that your editor/IDE respects the encoding declaration (`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` line at the top) and it uses the specified character encoding to save the Python source file.

Here's a complete code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals

L = ['A', 'C', 'Dxbensäce', '']
print(*L, sep=':')
```

#### Output

```
A:C:Dxbensäce:
```